# Why do we have to select the surrounding area of an object in photoshop while removing it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So, its common knowledge that when you use the patch/content-aware tool in photoshop while removing an object, you should include the surrounding area of the object that you want to remove in your selection for best results.

Why is that?

Photoshop uses the surrounding area to fill in the space that was occupied by the object after removing the object, right? Then why should we select some of the surrounding pixels for removal for "best results" ?

Comment: I wouldn't have said that this was 'common knowledge' or that it guarantees the 'best results' at all. Good practice for this kind of work is quite case dependent so please provide a specific example that you need help with.

Comment: its in the video "Remove and move objects in your photos with Photoshop" after 1:40

Comment: she clearly says we should add in the extra area around the object for best results

Comment: oops i posted the wrong link, sorry...here is the correct link - https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/lightroom-to-photoshop.html?playlist=/ccx/v1/collection/product/photoshop/segment/photographer/explevel/beginner/applaunch/basictraining/collection.ccx.js&promoid=45P49WN4

Answer (score 4):

You have three options:

1. Select part of the object
2. Select the exact object
3. Select a bit outside the object

**(1) Select part of the object** won't work because then you won't have your entire object removed.

**(2) Select the exact object** will work but completely defeats the point of using content-aware tools. You might as well be masking and stuff if you're going to go through the trouble of an exact outline.

**(3) Select a bit outside the object** is thus the only real way to do this. It's not best. The best would be to do an exact outline using more advanced functions. This is an efficient way to get good enough results.